# Images not aligning in the center of slick carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I decided to use the [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to do a carousel on this site I'm building and the carousel *works*, but I can't get the images to align in the center of the carousel and fill the page (if that makes sense?). I'm still pretty new at web development, so I'm sure I'm missing something. Anyways, here is my code....

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <main id="mainContent" role="main">
 <article role="article">
    <section>
        <header id="carousel">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="single-item-rtl" dir="rtl">
                    <div><img src="img/6.jpg" height="500px" width:"1500px" align= center/></div>
                    <div><img src="img/7.jpg"height="500px" width:"1500px" align= center/></div>
                    <div><img src="img/8.JPG" height="500px" width:"1500px" align= center/></div>
                    <div><img src="img/9.jpg" height="500px" width:"1500px" align= center/></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </section>
</article>
</main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">      </script>
<script type "text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate- 1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item-rtl').slick({
        rtl: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Brandon Grotesque";
src: url("fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg.otf") format("opentype");
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family:"Brandon Grotesque";
}

#mainContent {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.container {
  width: 1500px; 
  height:600px;      
  margin: auto; 
}
```

What I get with that code is this--->https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgjrw.jpg. Could anyone maybe explain to me what is is that I'm missing please? Preferably without laughing at me ;) Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you just have a link to your site? Or can you recreate this in a fiddle?

Comment: I do not. Sorry, its not hosted yet. I just started to build it. There is an screenshot of the browser posted at the bottom of my post though!

Comment: sorry...with just that screenshot its harder to debug..why dont you share a http://jsfiddle.net/#run with us..

Comment: I have jQuery set as the framework extension on jsFiddle, but I Don't think I can add the slick library because its only hosted locally....or can I? Also, how can I share this with you in a place where you can properly debug it? Sorry for all the questions. Thanks guys!

Comment: Slick library has CDN repositories: //cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js and //cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css

Comment: Add these to jsfiddle external resources

Comment: Ok I think i got it.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/dnewman/wvy42eqo/
Full screen result: http://jsfiddle.net/dnewman/wvy42eqo/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error with your `<img/>` markup, e.g., `<img src="img/6.jpg" height="500px" width:"1500px" align= center/>`.

It should be `<img src="img/6.jpg" height="500" width="1500" align= center/>`. Note the `=` instead of the `:`.

Also note that the `width` and `height` attributes do not take units. You probably want to specify the dimensions using the CSS properties, in which case your markup would look like `<img src="img/6.jpg" style="height:500px;width:1500px;text-align:center" />`

Answer (score 3):

Consider adding this CSS to `.slick-track` class:

```css
.slick-track {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for each image set the margin-left and margin-right auto.

```
<img src="..." style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
```